# Can I disable the Romantic Reputation in The Sims 3 Generations?

Tags: the-sims-3

In The Sims 3: Generations, how can I disable the romantic reputation system?

If it can't be disabled in the base game, is there a mod which can?

Comment: With `testingcheatenabled true`, ctrl+Click on the reputation and it should go away.

Comment: Before I got to the part about Sims 3, I thought `The Romantic Reputation` was a TF2 item.

Comment: @SteveV.: It's a (very annoying) gameplay mechanic in SIMS 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not disable it as far as i know but you can reset it, even in a legit way. With the generations expansion pack comes a new lifetime reward "clean slate" this resets all the reputation. This is the only legit and mod-less way of getting rid of your reputation. Not sure why you want this, if you do not mind cheats you can boost your lifetime points with a cheat and buy the clean slate reward that way.

Spoiler (cheat)

> Press CTRL+SHIFT+C to open up the console and type in "testingcheatsenabled true".
>  Now go to the lifetime happiness tab (where you see that treasure chest), hold SHIFT
>  And click on the treasure chest to add 500 per click.

Comment: Note - you should enter the cheat on the main menu screen, before you've loaded your save. In all my testing, it always works when I do it from the main menu, but I've only gotten it to work one time when I waited until I had loaded my game.